# How do I see my flags in the new profile view?

Tags: support, user-profile

I like the swanky new profiles as much as the next guy,  but I can't seem to find my flag/helpful flag count anywhere anymore. On the old profile, they were just at the top of the page under all the other stuff like name/location etc.

Where is my flag count now? A screenshot would be most helpful if possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's located under the Activity section

[image: Helpful Flag]

also should note that it is also a link to your flag list